# What is happening with html file with asp @page directive and content tags within it

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

With ASP.net I am familiar with creating a master page and then being able to set that master page for a .aspx file.

With one of our sites where I work we are given ftp access to edit static html pages.  Within these html pages are a few asp tags, specifically a page directive with title, language and masterpagefile attributes, and a few content tags with id, contentplaceholderid and runat attributes.

My question is how are they doing this?  If I were to add a master page in visual studio for my own project I am unable to pick a master page for .html files.  Are they somehow building/overwriting a .aspx file after upload? If I go to the website the url will show a .html extension.

Comment: right click on your master page and choose create content page. you can also nest master pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Within these html pages are a few asp tags, specifically a page directive with title, language and masterpagefile attributes, and a few content tags with id, contentplaceholderid and runat attributes.

Then the host is processing these `.html` files through the ASP.NET runtime before serving them.  At a technical level ASP.NET pages don't *need* to have the `.aspx` file extension, that's just by convention.  The web server can be configured to process any files as ASP.NET pages.

If you look through the configuration of IIS for example (and the specifics of that will vary wildly with IIS versions), you might find something like (and this may be quite dated, I haven't had to look under the hood in IIS for years) a mapping for `.aspx` files to `aspnet_isapi.dll`.  That same configuration can also be changed to also map `.html` files to `aspnet_isapi.dll`, which would process them the same way.

This isn't common practice not only because of convention but also because server-side processing adds overhead and is less performant than serving a static file directly from the web server.  Since `.html` files traditionally have static content, it's a lot faster to let IIS serve them directly than to process them through the ASP.NET engine.  It's *possible*, and the host in question seems to be doing exactly that, it's just uncommon for these reasons.

Comment: So if I hear you right they are simply html files set to be processed as asp.net pages. This seems to be what they are doing. At one time these files where completely static including a top menu. The top menu along with footer now must appear in their master page and the rest of content is editable by us.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio you can change the settings to serve Dynamic content.

> In Application Designer, you must specify whether an ASP.NET application exposes dynamic or static content. Dynamic content specifies that a script processor such as ASP.NET is required to run the application or any Web services associated with the application. Static content specifies that no script processor is required, for example, to run the application or to display HTML.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242474(v=vs.90).aspx